# Navigate Programmatically in Windows Media Center

Tags: c#, windows-7, windows-media-center

I'm developing an Windows Media Center add-in on a Win-7 machine (if that is relevant).

As with all add-ins, it implements

```
public void Launch(AddInHost host)
{
}
```

In the further code, I recieve instructions to navigate up/down/left/right in the media center. That means, If I'm on the start screen in Windows Media Center, I just want to go up from `TV` to `Movies` or left from `Libary` to `Play DVD`

How do I do this programmatically with the `AddInHost`? There is the `MediaCenterEnvironment.NavigateToPage()` function, which doesn't seem to be what I want. Is there even the possibility to do what I want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, there is just no way to do this via any API or so. WMC doesn't provide any.

Instead, I solved my Problem by using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(key);`

I posted my solution as an answer to another question here on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880133/1403593